# Traveling Salesman Divide and Conquer C++

Tags: c++, traveling-salesman, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to implement the Divide and Conquer Algorithm to solve the Traveling Salesman problem.
I divided the problem into smaller parts, but I have no idea what to do next.

Here is my code:

```
struct coordinate
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

vector<coordinate> coordinates; //Please assume it is filled with random coordinates

void DivideAndConquer(int divide)
{
    vector<vector<coordinate>> routes;
    vector<coordinate> empty;
    int check = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++)
    {   
        if (i == divide * check)
        {
            check++;
            routes.push_back(empty);
        }
        routes[check - 1].push_back(coordinates[i]);
    }

    //What now?
}
```

I also implemented methods to calculate distance:

```
float Distance(coordinate first, coordinate second)
{
    return sqrt(pow(second.x - first.x, 2) + pow(second.y - first.y, 2) * 1.0);
}

float RouteDistance(vector<coordinate> route, bool returnBack)
{
    float totalDistance = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < route.size(); i++)
    {
        totalDistance += Distance(route[i-1], route[i]);
    }
    if (returnBack) totalDistance += Distance(route[0], route[route.size() - 1]);

    return totalDistance;
}
```

I wrote Brute Force algorithm as well, which I believe can be used in divide and conquer.
It simply returns to most optimal route of given coordinate vector.

```
vector<coordinate> BruteForce(vector<coordinate> route)
{

    vector<int> turn;
    for (int i = 0; i < route.size(); i++) turn.push_back(i);

    int currentBestDistance = RouteDistance(route, true);
    vector<coordinate> currentBestRoute = route;

    do
    {
        vector<coordinate> newRoute;
        int newRouteDistance;

        for (int e : turn)
        {
            newRoute.push_back(route[e]);
        }
        newRouteDistance = RouteDistance(newRoute, false);

        if (newRouteDistance < currentBestDistance)
        {
            currentBestRoute = newRoute;
            currentBestDistance = newRouteDistance;
        }

    } while (next_permutation(turn.begin(), turn.end()));

    return currentBestRoute;
}
```

In DivideAndConquer it currently divides the coordinates vector into sub vectors size of the "divide" parameter we call the function with.
For example, let's assume this is our coordinates:

10 20
23 54
98 123
55 72
16 82

And we call  "DivideAndConquer(2)"
result:

10 20
23 54

98 123
55 72

16 82

Comment: I've never heard of solving TSP using divide-and-conquer before and I think you're probably going in the wrong direction. Can you explain how you're dividing the problem?

Comment: @BessieTheCow Honestly I am doing an assignment that wants us to solve TSP with different algorithms. I implemented all wanted algorithms except Divide and Conquer. We have no hint or explanations so I really don't know which direction I should follow. About your question, currently, I am only dividing the "coordinates" vector into smaller vectors and put the results into "routes" the vector of vectors.